# Racket Function with Two Arguments

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

I'm trying to review my final exam in R5RS, but having trouble with a simple problem. My professor isn't really helpful and I don't know anybody in my class. Can you help me?

The function ratio takes in two parameters f (function) and x (a number). I had to use a let statement. The scheme function is supposed to produced an outcome for:

f(x)+f(x+1)/f(x)

This is what I have so far:

```
(define (ratio f x)
  (let ((f (+ x 1)))
    (/ (+ x (+ f 1))
       x)))

(ratio (lambda (x) (+ x 2)) 3)
```

I tried working with this for an hour, but still can't get the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: let `a = f(x)` and let `b = f(x + 1)`. What should the output be in terms of `a` and `b`?

In your solution, you bind `f` to the value of `x + 1`. So your solution is really calculating `(x + (x + 2)) / x`. You need to apply `f` to `x`, ie `(f x)`.

Here is a start:

```
(define (ratio f x)
  (let ((a (f x)) (b (f (+ x 1))))
    ...))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Math               Scheme
f(x)               (f x)
x+1                (+ x 1)
f(x+1)             (f (+ x 1))
a/b                (/ a b)
a/f(x)             (/ a (f x))
f(x+1)/f(x)        (/ (f (+ x 1)) (f x))
c + f(x+1)/f(x)    ?
f(x) + f(x+1)/f(x) ?
```